# OpenVZ - Ubuntu 12.04 unable to enter

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, openvz

I've setup an Ubuntu 12.04 on OpenVZ, it's been created and appears to start up fine. When I try to enter the OS it just hangs.

I've ran ps aux with the exec and it returns:

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.2   2980  1436 ?        Ss   Jan31   0:00 init
root      3499  0.0  0.1   2816  1048 ?        Rs   Feb01   0:00 ps aux
```

Any ideas why I am unable to enter the machine?

Thanks

Comment: Sure. Lone running `/sbin/init` is definitely not enough task set to process your login ateempts.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are running on 2.6.32-* kernel? Otherwise if you are on the old 2.6.18 kernel you need to do some modifications for it to work ...

Add `"ubuntu-12.04 2.6.32"` to `/etc/vz/osrelease.conf`